# Does stackPanel1.Children.RemoveAt destroy (dispose) the control?

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, runtime, destroy

I am composing new webbrowser elements like the way below

```
webnew = new WebBrowser();
webnew.Height = 1024;
webnew.Width = 768;
webnew.Name = "webBrowser1";
webnew.Navigated += new NavigatedEventHandler(wbMain_Navigated);
stackPanel1.Children.Add(webnew);
webnew.Navigate("url");
```

Now when i remove the element at stackPanel1 like the way below does it get destroyed completely ? I want it to be completely destroyed and removed from ram. If not how to completely destroy such dynamically composed element ? Thank you.

```
  stackPanel1.Children.RemoveAt(0);
```

C# , C# 4.0 , WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,  eventually when the [garbage collector](http://ashishkhandelwal.arkutil.com/?p=1832) gets to it.

However, since WebBrowser implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) - you should really call

```
webnew.Dispose()
```

before removing it from the stackpanel.